# values extraction based on matching in different matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices of type character. Having values like:

```
>head(pData(eset))[1:3,1:2]

               title geo_accession                

GSM118720 EC2003090503AA     GSM118720 

GSM118721 EC2003090502AA     GSM118721 

GSM118722 EC2003090504AA     GSM118722 

>head(cont)[1:3,6:8]

array2     perturbation_scan_id vehicle_scan_id3  

1 "HG-U133A" "EC2003090503AA"     "EC2003090502AA" 

2 "HG-U133A" "EC2003090504AA"     "EC2003090502AA" 

3 "HG-U133A" "EC2003090505AA"     "EC2003090502AA"
```

I want to get those values from `cont[,'perturbation_scan_id']` where corresponding `cont[,'vehicle_scan_id3']` is in `(pData(eset))$title`.

I want to pass a `character`

```
> Title_name

[1] "EC2003090503AA" "EC2003090502AA" "EC2003090504AA"
```

to `cont` matrix so that it will return me the values in `vehicle_scan_id3` column which corresponds to these `Title_name` values in `perturbation_scan_id` column.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you are having?

Comment: I am trying following command: but it is not working fine.

Comment: Control_title <- as.character(cont[,'vehicle_scan_id3'])[cont[,'perturbation_scan_id'] == Title_name]

Comment: Logic in my mind for it is: Return me those values from 'vehicle_scan_id3' of cont (matrix) where values of 'perturbation_scan_id' (in 'cont' matrix) are equal to values in "Title_name" object.

Comment: Maybe `cont[cont$perturbation_scan_id %in% Title_name,"vehicle_scan_id3"]` ?. Is `cont` a matrix or a dataframe? If `class(cont)` is matrix, run `cont<-as.data.frame(cont)` first

Comment: Or maybe [merging](http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html)? May require renaming of columns.

Comment: NicE your suggestions worked. I tried: Control_title <- as.character(cont[cont$perturbation_scan_id %in% Title_name,"vehicle_scan_id3"]) . But now when I am using Control_title for retrieving row.names of 1st matrix (based on matching) I am getting following error: Control_Row_name <- row.names(pData(eset))[(pData(eset))$title == Control_title]
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`((pData(eset))$title, Control_title) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %in% operator together with the which function to accomplish this as follows:

```
Control_title <- as.character(cont[which(cont$perturbation_scan_id %in% Title_name), 'vehicle_scan_id3'])
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

> Control_title <- as.character(cont[cont$perturbation_scan_id %in% Title_name,"vehicle_scan_id3"])
>
> Control_title
> [1] "EC2003121202AA" "EC2004011602AA" "EC2004021313AA"

But when I use 'Control_title' to retrieve row.names of 1st matrix it doesn't work and produce following Warning message:

> Control_Row_name <- row.names(pData(eset))[(pData(eset))$title == Control_title]

Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`((pData(eset))$title, Control_title) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

And gives Output of only 1 value, not 3 of them.

> Control_Row_name

[1] "GSM118799"

Comment: Also solved this one by: Control_Row_name <- row.names(pData(eset))[(pData(eset))$title %in% Control_title] . Thanks everyone for your response, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your suggestions !! Anyhow, thanks :)